# Set squash boolean when creating a merge request from a url

Tags: gitlab

When creating a merge request in gitlab, you can add parameters to the url to have them automatically filled out in the MR form. For example, `merge_request[source_branch]=new-feature` will set the source branch as `new-feature`, and `merge_request[title]=add+new+feature` will set the MR's title to "add new feature". A final MR url could look something like:

```
https://my-gitlab/group/project/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=new-feature&merge_request%5Btarget_branch%5D=master&merge_request%5Btitle%5D=add+new+feature
```

One setting that I'd like to be able to automatically set via the url is whether or not to squash commits upon merge. According to the [gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr), one of the available params for an MR POST request is a boolean `squash`. However, this doesn't seem to apply to a URL request. When I add `&merge_request%5Bsquash%5D=false` to my URL, the MR is created with the default squash enabled.

Is there a way to get the effect I'm looking for using the `merge_requests/new?...` URL? Am I formatting something wrong?

Comment: Also stumbled across this issue. Seems like this wasn't and won't get fixed [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/297248)

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is a link to Gitlab page (**not Gitlab API**) which redirects you to create MR page with preset source and target branch and it creates **MR** with your **current project settings**.

To make all your MRs have `Squash` option set by default go to:

**Project -> Settings -> General -> Merge requests** and in section **Squash commits when merging** set **Encourage**.

[image: Encourage Squashing Gitlab Project Setting]

Using [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) you can create MR with proper settings regardless of project settings.

I tried the API with `Squash` parameter on public Gitlab and it works like a charm:

```sh
curl -X POST \
     --fail \
     --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <YOUR PERSONAL API TOKEN>' \
     -F source_branch=<source branch name> \
     -F target_branch=master \
     -F title=FromCurlApi \
     -F squash=true \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/14385369/merge_requests
```